# The method 'where' was called on null. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am Streaming a list from Firestore and I get an error anytime I run the app.

```
static Stream<List<ToDo>> readToDo() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('todo2')
  .orderBy(ToDoField.createdTime, descending: true)
  .snapshots()
  .transform(Utils.transformer(ToDo.fromJson));
```

`List<ToDo> _todos = [];`

`List<ToDo> get todos => _todos.where((todo) => todo.isDone == false).toList();`

Th error

`The method 'where' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: where(Closure: (ToDo) => bool)`

Comment: You need to share more code to see when/where do you initialize the list `_todos`.

Comment: Is shown  in the codes the second code... the. Empty list... the problem is null safety issue

Comment: @Kekeli.dev I am also stuck at the same error.. Do you know how can I fix it?

my Code:

    var temp;

    temp = Firestore.instance
        .collection('devices')
        .where('owner', isEqualTo: _user.uid)
        .snapshots();